# Constant variable is changing but not in memory

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers, constants

First of all, I am working in XCode C++ when I get the error. I declare a pointer variable as a constant and I set the value once. Then in the code a loop runs 3-5 times and the first time it is correct but then depending on the number of variables, the value of the coordinate changes to close to 0 (ie. 4.59163e-41). I know that the memory address does not change, just the value it holds does. Also I am working with really large amounts of data, and by that I mean between 2,000 and 20,000 coordinates. I'm sure I caused this with either a big or small problem so any help would be appreciated. Below is some of the code for the changing [not-so] constant variable:

I declare them in the header file as:

```
const float* m_xPointValues;
const float* m_yPointValues;
```

Then in the .cpp file I set them in the following function:

```
void ccGraphDisplay::setPointValues(float* xPointValues, float* yPointValues, unsigned numberOfPoints)
{
    assert(xPointValues);
    assert(yPointValues);

    m_xPointValues = xPointValues;
    m_yPointValues = yPointValues;
    m_numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;

....}
```

Then in the looping function I shift them but as far as I know this does NOT change their value:

```
for (unsigned i=0;i<m_numberOfPoints;++i)
{
    shiftedXValue = (((m_xPointValues[i] - m_xAbsoluteMin)/(m_xAbsoluteMax-m_xAbsoluteMin))*(m_roi[2]-m_roi[0]))+m_roi[0];
    shiftedYValue = (((m_yPointValues[i] - m_yAbsoluteMin)/(m_yAbsoluteMax-m_yAbsoluteMin))*(m_roi[3]-m_roi[1]))+m_roi[1];
}
```

To me this is a very odd error. I do not change the value of m_xPointValues or m_yPointValues anywhere else and in the largest sets of data only the end portion of the coordinates change. I also set the loop to print out the values at the beginning and end of the loop and the end is always the same as the beginning but then when the loop starts over is when the value of it changes.

Finally some of the debugging ideas I have already tried include:
1) Changing the pointer from storing floats to doubles
2) Changing the pointers to no longer be constant
3) Passing in constant values (both double and float)

Any help would be greatly appreciated (including ideas to try!).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the locations pointed to by `xPointValues` and `yPointValues`, that you passed to `setPointValues`, do not have the same lifetime as `m_xPointValues` and `m_yPointValues`.

Comment: Thank you! It was the way I was declaring them. I originally had them as: float xPointValues [numberOfPoints]; but by changing them to: float* xPointValues = new float [numberOfPoints]; they are no longer deleted after the function runs.